# indexOf assertion issue

Tags: java, arrays, assertion

```
public int indexOf(X s)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i].equals(s))
        {
            return i;
        } 
    }        
    return -1;
}
```

.

```
@Test
public void testIndexOf()
{
    BetterArray<String> b = new BetterArray<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        b.add("str" + i);

    assertEquals(0, b.indexOf("str0"));
    assertEquals(19, b.indexOf("str19"));
    assertEquals(-1, b.indexOf("not found"));
}
```

The code on top does not pass the final assertion in the test, but the first 2 seem to be going fine, to me it looks like if it loops through and does not find the string, it'll return -1, am i missing something?

Comment: Have you tried printing out what `b.indexOf("not found")` actually *is* returning?

Comment: You'll have to give us a reproducible example. This seems fine.

Comment: (Also, just to confirm, is `arr` an array of `X`'s?)

Comment: yes arr is X[]. and i havent tried printing it out because BlueJ is being weird and not showing output on codepad

Comment: [Here's an Ideone](http://ideone.com/8JOXyu) that shows this is fine so the problem is elsewhere. Something else you should try is to make sure to recompile the whole project.

Comment: yeah i did recompile several times, thats weird that it works, i assume dit did too. it says the problem is at the line arr[i].equals(s)), so not sure what to think of it =/

Comment: Well you need to show us the rest of the code. At the moment my assumption is that `arr.length` is longer than the number of elements you've added and you are actually getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: lol uhh yeah, i changed it to "< length" and it worked, like you said.  but how does that even make a difference isnt it just looping to the end of the array, whats causing a null?

Comment: Arrays in Java are **zero-based**, so index can go from `0` to `length-1`.

Comment: Maybe check your constructor, the add() method, and any place where `arr` is changed to make sure that the underlying array `arr` really reflects what you expect it to be.